# how to get back original prediction from Time Series Forecasting in R with Holt-Winters

Tags: r, prediction, forecasting

I am in the process of analyzing the amount of the transfer from diaSpora TO HAITI.
Before I predict values in the future, I have to create a fit to the data. without any issue, my data is Fitting with Holt-Winters and the fits is a good quality. HOW i get back original prediction from Time Series Forecasting in R with Holt-Winters?

```
LESN<-HoltWinters(log(TRFR), beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE) # ParamC(tres: alpha, beta, gamma : Lissage Exponentiel Simple, serie en log

plot(LESN)
FLESN<-forecast(LESN, h=24)|>as.data.frame() # RC)alisation de la prevision en Log sous forme data frame\\
forecast2 = forecast:::forecast.HoltWinters(LESN, h=24)|>as.data.frame()
#
str(LESN)
LESN$fitted
## REALISATION DE LA PREVISION EN NIVEAU
#
## 2. MODELE EN DIFFERENCE PREMIERE
#
LESD<-HoltWinters(diff(log(TRFR)), beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE) # ParamC(tres: alpha, beta, gamma: Lissage Exponentiel Simple, serie en diff. prem. log
plot(LESD)
FLESD<-forecast(LESD, h=24)|>as.data.frame() #
```